# Close button event in libgdx

Tags: button, libgdx

How to override libgdx window "X" button method?

For example I want to add dialog: "Are you sure you want to close app?" with two buttons "Yes" and "No" to confirm the choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your game implements `ApplicationListener` (most I´ve seen do this), when you press the "X" button, `dispose()` gets called.

You can create your dialog on the `dispose()` function.

**Edit:** Little note, if your main game class extends `Game` (LibGDX Class), you can use this method, `Game` implements `ApplicationListener`.